# maximum of distance

Tags: calculus, geometry

there are n segments ，we choose two points on every segments denote by $$ a_i ，b_i$$，now how to get the maximum of $$ ｜\sum Oa_i-\sum Ob_i｜$$
O is the origin ，$$Oa_i$$ is a vector

Comment: Is this a 2-d problem? In any event, if $p_k, q_k = p_k + t_k$ are end points of $k^{th}$ segment, then
$$\sum_k a_k - \sum_k b_k = \sum_k (a_k - b_k) = \sum_k \lambda_k t_k$$ 
for some $\lambda_k \in [-1,1]$. Since the distance function is convex, maximum appear at boundary. To maximize $\left|\sum_k \lambda_k t_k\right|$, you only need to look at those combinations where all $|\lambda_k|  = 1$.

Comment: @achillehui I have  the question that how to know the $\lambda$ is positive or negative

Comment: In general, there is no analytic solution for the sign of $\lambda_k$. The problem is similar to convex optimization enough and there should be algorithm to compute the $\lambda_k$. Unfortunately, I don't know any of them. The only thing I know is in 2-d, there are simplification that allow you to look at $n$  (instead of $2^{n-1}$ ) combinations of $\lambda_k$.

Comment: @achillehui the problem is just in 2-d，and this simplification is enough，could you teach me？ thanks

Comment: Let $t_k = r_k(\cos\theta_k,\sin\theta_k)$. Flip direction and reorder if necessary, we will assume
$-\frac{\pi}{2} < \theta_1 < \theta_2 < \cdots < \theta_n \le \frac{\pi}{2}$.
One of following $n$ combinations will maximize $|\sum_k \lambda_k t_k|$.

$$t_1 + \dots + t_n, -t_1 + (t_2 + \cdots + t_n), -(t_1 + t_2) + (t_3 + \cdots + t_n),\cdots,\\
-(t_1 + \cdots + t_{n-2}) + (t_{n-1}+t_n),
-(t_1 + \cdots + t_{n-1}) + t_n$$
i.e. the one with positive $\lambda_k$ and negative $\lambda_k$ falls into at most two consecutive blocks.

Comment: @achillehui can you tell me why this algorithm take effect？ I have thought it for a long time

Comment: Let $\mu_k$ be a set of $\lambda_k$ which maximize $\left|\sum_{k}\lambda_k t_k\right|$. Let $u = \sum_k \mu_k t_k$. Since $\mu_k$ maximize $\left|\sum_{k}\lambda_k t_k\right|$, for any $j$, we have $|u|^2 \ge |u - 2\mu_j t_j|^2 \implies u\cdot (\mu_j v_j) \ge |v_j|^2 > 0$. To maximize $|\sum_k \lambda_k t_k|$, we only need to look at those configurations of $\lambda_k$ where all $\lambda_k t_k$ falls in some half space. In 2-d, when we order the vectors $t_k$ as I have described before, the up to a minus sign, this half-space requirement limit the candidate of $u$ to the one I mentioned.